# Getting PayPal Pro to work with Mijireh/WooCOmmerce

Tags: paypal, wordpress, woocommerce, mijireh

I am trying to get Mijireh to work with my woocommerce website, using the PayPal Pro (UK) payment gateway.

Basically, I have a Mijireh account and have gone through the stages to make it live. 
I have also added my Mijireh access key to my site and slurped the Mijireh checkout page.

I have recently signed up to PayPal Pro UK (£20/month) so that I can use it with Mijireh.

I have gone into my PayPal Pro account and requested API credentials which gives me an API username and password.

So I have gone onto my Mijireh account and added these as the payment gateway under login and password. However, when I try to make an order, I get an error message that states invalid credentials.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and Mijireh documentation is pitiful. So I am turning here to see if anyone can offer advice, if not I will just give up with Mijireh.

Answer (score 0):

I've been going round and round with this problem as well then I found this...

http://spencercarli.com/2014/01/payflow-pro-mijireh-checkout/

Seems Mijereh is not paypal compatable